# How to recursively walk a binary tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have the following question for a quiz I couldn't solve:

Given a tree represented `(5, (3, (20, (6, None, None), None), None), (10, (1, None, None), (15, (30, None, (9, None, None)), (8, None, None))))`, where the first item is the node, the second item is a left branching tree, and the third item is a right branching tree, find the largest zigzag (option to change direction in the tree).

So this tree starts at 5, goes left to 3 or right to 10, from 3 it would go left to 20 (it can't go right, right is `None`). Walking from 10 it can go left to 1, or right to 15, etc

I failed it as I was having problems even recursively walking a tree. I couldn't determine how to choose to walk left or right, and when walking the tree the second, third, etc time, how do know it was walked that path before?

I had here

```
 class Tree(object):

     def __init__(self, zigzags, node, left, right):
         self.zigzags = zigzags
         self.node = node
         self.left = left
         self.right = right

TREE = (5, (3, (20, (6, None, None), None), None), (10, (1, None, None), (15, (30, None, (9, None, None)), (8, None, None))))



def walk_tree(tree, current_direction='l', zigzag_count=0, this_path=''):
    left = tree[1]
    right = tree[2]

    print('left:')
    print(left)

    print('right:')
    print(right)

    print('zigzag_count:')
    print(zigzag_count)

    possible_left_path = this_path + 'l'  # say like 'lrl'
    possible_right_path = this_path + 'r' # say like 'lrr'

    if left:
        if current_direction == 'r':
            zigzag_count += 1
        return walk_tree(left, 'l', zigzag_count)

    elif right:
        if current_direction == 'l':
            zigzag_count += 1
        return walk_tree(right, 'r', zigzag_count)

    else:
        return zigzag_count

count = walk_tree(TREE)
print(count)
```

Which I believed walked down the left side then stopped:

```
$ ./exam_question_2.py 
left:
(3, (20, (6, None, None), None), None)
right:
(10, (1, None, None), (15, (30, None, (9, None, None)), (8, None, None)))
zigzag_count:
0
left:
(20, (6, None, None), None)
right:
None
zigzag_count:
0
left:
(6, None, None)
right:
None
zigzag_count:
0
left:
None
right:
None
zigzag_count:
0
0
```

The expected answer is 2, walking right, right, left, right.

I want to try to solve the zigzagging just to learn, but I'd like to know how to just recursively walk this binary tree in this format, and know when I change walks (when I start at the top again), and some theory behind it if possible.  I'd prefer an example in Python or JavaScript.

Comment: So the goal is to find the *longest path* where you change direction each step? So either left - right - left - right or right - left - right - left? You don't need to recurse, you just need to test the two paths (the one starting to the left, or the one starting to the right).

Comment: Close, it's to find the longest path of zigzag. The zigzag can be anywhere in the tree, it doesn't have to start at the top. Essentially all possible paths from the top have to be checked, and the amount of alternations from left, to right, to left ,etc have to be counted. In the answer, the answer was right, right, left, right, so 2 zigzags...right to left, then left to right. The sample used is what I gave as `TREE`

Comment: since the zigzag can be anywhere, even near the bottom of one of the branches, they suggested recursing

Comment: So, given all possible paths, find the path with the most changes in direction?

Comment: Yes that's it  .

Comment: You are only following *either* the left (if it is not `None`), or the right child. You need to follow *both*, then determine which one of those is the better candidate. For a given subtree, return the higher zigzag value and path of the two (prepending the chosen direction to the path you return). Recursion stops for the empty subtree (return `0, ''` for that).

Comment: You are only testing one path: Starting left if there is a left, or starting right if there is a right and no left.

Comment: What's the expected result for your example?

Comment: the answer is 2

Comment: @codyc4321: you could [edit] your question to include those details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical divide-and-conquer problem. Given a node with children, the zigzag score for that node is that of the child with the highest zigzag score (with 1 added if reaching that child required a change of direction):

```
def zigzagscore(node):
    left, right = node[1:]

    left_zigzag, left_path = 0, ''
    if left is not None:
        left_zigzag, left_path = zigzagscore(left)
        if left_path.startswith('r'):
            # We zigged for left
            left_zigzag += 1
        left_path = 'l' + left_path

    right_zigzag, right_path = 0, ''
    if right is not None:
        right_zigzag, right_path = zigzagscore(right)
        if right_path.startswith('l'):
            # We zagged for right
            right_zigzag += 1
        right_path = 'r' + right_path

    if left_zigzag > right_zigzag:
        return left_zigzag, left_path
    else:
        return right_zigzag, right_path
```

Your code never considered the right path when there is a left node available.

This produces your expected path:

```
>>> TREE = (5, (3, (20, (6, None, None), None), None), (10, (1, None, None), (15, (30, None, (9, None, None)), (8, None, None))))
>>> zigzagscore(TREE)
(2, 'rrlr')
```

Comment: `zigzagscore(node)` is boring, I would've called it `zz(top)`

Comment: Ok, so because the highest level of `zigzagscore`, the `left, right = node[1:]` part, starts up there, and you decide whether to call itself again with right or left, so it does recurse each line down the tree. Ya actually applying recursion is harder than reading about it. Thanks again Martijn

Comment: I sent a more enjoyable thank you, a Munchkin thingy. Amazon said it'll be there by September 9. Thanks

Comment: @StefanPochmann please provide an answer copy and pasting Martijn's solution, with the renamed function and a picture of a ZZ Top lookalike with a similar beard, and I will accept.

Comment: @codyc4321: thanks! That's *hugely* appreciated! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Adopting a recursive approach, you can state the following rule:

Le longest zigzag from the current node, if reached from the left, is the longest between the longest left zigzag and the longest right zigzag plus one; and conversely if reached from the right.

The rule differs for the root node, as it is not reached from any side.

```
def Length(Node, FromLeft):
  if Node == None:
    return 0
  return max(Length(Node.Left, True) + (1 if not FromLeft else 0), Length(Node.Left, False) + (1 if FromLeft else 0))

print max(Length(Root.Left, True), Length(Root.Right, False))
```

I made no use of the zigzag field, but of course this is doable.